# Dynamic Single Function As Multiple Name and Get Function Name as Parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, function

Can I call a function by defining multiple alias

My standard functions:

```
function Green { process { Write-Host -NoNewline $_ -ForegroundColor  Green } }
function Red { process { Write-Host -NoNewline $_  -ForegroundColor  Red } }
function Yellow { process { Write-Host -NoNewline $_  -ForegroundColor  Yellow } }
```

Standard result:

```
$var = "Hello, World"
Write-Output "$var" | Green        # WARNING: Dont like "<functionname> <param>"
Write-Output "$var" | Yellow       # WARNING: Dont like "<functionname> <param>"
Write-Output "$var" | Yellow       # WARNING: Dont like "<functionname> <param>"
```

Expected function:

```
function **Green,Red,Yellow** { process { Write-Host -NoNewline $_ -ForegroundColor **<functionName>** } }
```

Comment: You can have multiple aliases for same parameter.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: but what I want is not such an alias definition, I'm trying to dynamically search if such a feature exists.

Comment: Ok, I understood the function now, then I accomplish my purposes with calculation lenght of my bar thank u again.

Comment: You can use `-ForegroundColor $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` but you would still need 3 functions for each color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution but this would accomplish what you are looking for, basically dynamically defining a function per value in the [`ConsoleColor` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=net-7.0).

```
$def = {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object] $InputObject
    )
    begin {
        $pipe = { Write-Host -ForegroundColor $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name }.
            GetSteppablePipeline()

        $pipe.Begin($true)
    }
    process {
        $pipe.Process($InputObject)
    }
    end {
        $pipe.End()
    }
}

# If you just want Green, Yellow and Red you can change to:
# 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red' | ForEach-Object {
[System.Enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor]) | ForEach-Object {
    & (New-Item "function:$_" -Value $def -Force) "Defined function: '$_'"
}

# Testing:
'foo' | Green
'bar' | Yellow
'baz' | Red

Magenta foo, bar, baz
```

Comment: on terminal is ok, but I couldn't apply it insde script file, i dont know why when I adding to the script file and run, it is not active

Comment: Can I put all above commands inside single function?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki no. single function is not possible. if you have the functions in the file you need to dot source the file, `. .\file.ps1` note the dot before the path

Comment: Is it even possible to turn only this part into a function or not? :(  `...[System.Enum]::GetValues...`

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki that part is creating 1 function per each color existing in that enum.

Comment: The notification message after creating dynamic functions confused me, when I tried to delete it, the newline increased `Defined function: 'DarkYellow' etc..`

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki if you just want to define the functions without producing any output you can change `& (New-Item "function:$_" -Value $def -Force) "Defined function: '$_'"` to `$null = New-Item "function:$_" -Value $def -Force`. Then you will have a function per color like in the testing section of the code

Comment: Thanks to you, I learned how to create a dynamic function instance.